# Hugging face HTTP request on data from parquet format when the only way to get it is from the website's data viewer, how to fix?

Tags: nlp, huggingface, huggingface-datasets, huggingface-hub

Due to Hugging Face datasets disappearing, I've had to get the data from their data viewer using the parquet option. But when I try to run it,  there is some sort of HTTP error. I've tried downloading the data but I can't. What is the recommended way to solve this problem?

Partial code (and [full code](https://github.com/brando90/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/blob/4b26da53c8a39c07183e43497f03621c25480481/src/diversity/div_coeff.py#L517)):

```py
    # - 5 subsets of the pile interleaved
    # from diversity.pile_subset_urls import urls_hacker_news, urls_nih_exporter, urls_pubmed, urls_uspto
    # from diversity.data_mixtures import get_uniform_data_mixture_5subsets_of_pile, get_doremi_data_mixture_5subsets_of_pile, get_llama_v1_data_mixtures_5subsets_of_pile
    # path, name, data_files, split = ['suolyer/pile_pile-cc'] + ['parquet'] * 4, [None] + ['hacker_news', 'nih_exporter', 'pubmed', 'uspto'], [None] + [urls_hacker_news, urls_nih_exporter, urls_pubmed, urls_uspto], ['validation'] + ['train'] * 4
    # ## path, name, data_files = ['conceptofmind/pile_cc'] + ['parquet'] * 4, ['sep_ds'] + ['hacker_news', 'nih_exporter', 'pubmed', 'uspto'], [None] + [urls_hacker_news, urls_nih_exporter, urls_pubmed, urls_uspto]
    # # probabilities, data_mixture_name = get_uniform_data_mixture_5subsets_of_pile()
    # # probabilities, data_mixture_name = get_llama_v1_data_mixtures_5subsets_of_pile(name)
    # probabilities, data_mixture_name = get_doremi_data_mixture_5subsets_of_pile(name)
    # - probe net
    pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf'
    # - not changing
    batch_size = 512
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-m%m-d%d-t%Hh_%Mm_%Ss')
    run_name = f'{path} div_coeff_{num_batches=} ({today=} ({name=}) {data_mixture_name=} {probabilities=} {pretrained_model_name_or_path=})'
    print(f'\n---> {run_name=}\n')

    # - Init wandb
    debug: bool = mode == 'dryrun'
    run = wandb.init(mode=mode, project="beyond-scale", name=run_name, save_code=True)
    wandb.config.update({"num_batches": num_batches, "path": path, "name": name, "today": today, 'probabilities': probabilities, 'batch_size': batch_size, 'debug': debug, 'data_mixture_name': data_mixture_name, 'streaming': streaming, 'data_files': data_files, 'seed': seed, 'pretrained_model_name_or_path': pretrained_model_name_or_path})
    # run.notify_on_failure() # https://community.wandb.ai/t/how-do-i-set-the-wandb-alert-programatically-for-my-current-run/4891
    print(f'{debug=}')
    print(f'{wandb.config=}')

    # -- Get probe network
    from datasets import load_dataset 
    from datasets.iterable_dataset import IterableDataset
    import torch
    from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel

    # tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    # if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
    #     tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    # probe_network = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    # device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    # probe_network = probe_network.to(device)

    from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoTokenizer
    torch_dtype = torch.bfloat16
    torch_dtype = torch.float32
    bf16=torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8,  # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        pretrained_model_name_or_path,
        # quantization_config=quantization_config,
        # device_map=device_map,  # device_map = None  https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/01c4a35928f41ba25b1d0032a085519b8065c843/examples/scripts/sft_trainer.py#L82
        trust_remote_code=True,
        torch_dtype=torch_dtype,
        use_auth_token=True,
    )
    print(f'{pretrained_model_name_or_path=}')
    # https://github.com/artidoro/qlora/blob/7f4e95a68dc076bea9b3a413d2b512eca6d004e5/qlora.py#L347C13-L347C13
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        pretrained_model_name_or_path,
        # cache_dir=args.cache_dir,
        padding_side="right",
        use_fast=False, # Fast tokenizer giving issues.
        # tokenizer_type='llama' if 'llama' in args.model_name_or_path else None, # Needed for HF name change
        # tokenizer_type='llama',
        trust_remote_code=True,
        use_auth_token=True,
    )
    if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
        tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    probe_network = model

    # -- Get data set
    def my_load_dataset(path, name, data_files=data_files, split=split):
        print(f'{path=} {name=} {streaming=} {data_files=}, {split=}')
        if path == 'json' or path == 'bin' or path == 'csv':
            print(f'{data_files_prefix+name=}')
            return load_dataset(path, data_files=data_files_prefix+name, streaming=streaming, split=split).with_format("torch")
        elif path == 'parquet':
            print(f'{data_files=}')
            return load_dataset(path, data_files=data_files, streaming=streaming, split=split).with_format("torch")
```

How to fix it? Ideas:

1. Download the parquet data
2. Stop the http error.

---

Error messages follow:

```
3345 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
3346 Traceback (most recent call last):
3347   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
3348     resp = conn.urlopen(
3349   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
3350     retries = retries.increment(
3351   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
3352     raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
3353   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
3354     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
3355   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
3356     httplib_response = self._make_request(
3357   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
3358     six.raise_from(e, None)
3359   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
3360   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 461, in _make_request
3361     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
3362   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1375, in getresponse
3363     response.begin()
3364   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
3365     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
3366   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 287, in _read_status
3367     raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
3368 urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
3369 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
3370 Traceback (most recent call last):
3371   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/div_coeff.py", line 591, in <module>
3372     print(f'{all_columns=}')
3373   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/div_coeff.py", line 553, in experiment_compute_diveristy_coeff_single_dataset_then_combined_datasets_with_domain_weights
3374   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/div_coeff.py", line 64, in get_diversity_coefficient
3375     embedding, loss = Task2Vec(probe_network, classifier_opts={'seed': seed}).embed(tokenized_batch)
3376   File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/task2vec.py", line 133, in embed
3377     loss = self._finetune_classifier(dataset, loader_opts=self.loader_opts, classifier_opts=self.classifier_opts, max_samples=self.max_samples, epochs=epochs)
3378   File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/task2vec.py", line 198, in _finetune_classifier
3379     for step, batch in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
3380   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1182, in __iter__
3381     for obj in iterable:
3382   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 633, in __next__
3383     data = self._next_data()
3384   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 677, in _next_data
3385     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
3386   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 32, in fetch
3387     data.append(next(self.dataset_iter))
3388   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 1353, in __iter__
3389     for key, example in ex_iterable:
3390   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 652, in __iter__
3391     yield from self._iter()
3392   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 667, in _iter
3393     for key, example in iterator:
3394   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 1088, in __iter__
3395     for key, example in self.ex_iterable:
3396   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 1013, in __iter__
3397     yield from islice(self.ex_iterable, self.n)
3398   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 400, in __iter__
3399     yield next(iterators[i])
3400   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 73, in __next__
3401     result = next(self.it)
3402   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 652, in __iter__
3403     yield from self._iter()
3404   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 714, in _iter
3405     for key, example in iterator:
3406   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 1088, in __iter__
3407     for key, example in self.ex_iterable:
3408   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 255, in __iter__
3409     for key, pa_table in self.generate_tables_fn(**self.kwargs):
3410   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/packaged_modules/parquet/parquet.py", line 77, in _generate_tables
3411     parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(f)
3412   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/core.py", line 334, in __init__
3413     self.reader.open(
3414   File "pyarrow/_parquet.pyx", line 1220, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetReader.open
3415   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/download/streaming_download_manager.py", line 333, in read_with_retries
3416     out = read(*args, **kwargs)
3417   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1790, in read
3418     out = self.cache._fetch(self.loc, self.loc + length)
3419   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/caching.py", line 156, in _fetch
3420     self.cache = self.fetcher(start, end)  # new block replaces old
3421   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/hf_file_system.py", line 404, in _fetch_range
3422     r = http_backoff("GET", url, headers=headers)
3423   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_http.py", line 258, in http_backoff
3424     response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
3425   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
3426     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
3427   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
3428     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
3429   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_http.py", line 63, in send
3430     return super().send(request, *args, **kwargs)
3431   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
3432     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
3433 requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: (ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')), '(Request ID: d98c4e56-198a-40cb-a53e-9e1348ea1c58)')
```

How does one solve this issue in the context of hugging face?

---

Error:

```
300   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
2301     httplib_response = self._make_request(
2302   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
2303     six.raise_from(e, None)
2304   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
2305   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 461, in _make_request
2306     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
2307   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1375, in getresponse
2308     response.begin()
2309   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
2310     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
2311   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 287, in _read_status
2312     raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
2313 http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
2314 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2315 Traceback (most recent call last):
2316   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
2317     resp = conn.urlopen(
2318   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
2319     retries = retries.increment(
2320   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
2321     raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
2322   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
2323     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
2324   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
2325     httplib_response = self._make_request(
2326   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
2327     six.raise_from(e, None)
2328   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
2329   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 461, in _make_request
2330     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
2331   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1375, in getresponse
2332     response.begin()
2333   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
2334     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
2335   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/beyond_scale/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 287, in _read_status
2336     raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
2337 urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
2338 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2339 Traceback (most recent call last):
2340   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/div_coeff.py", line 695, in <module>
2341     datasets = [dataset.remove_columns(columns_to_remove) for dataset in datasets]
2342   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/div_coeff.py", line 656, in experiment_compute_diveristy_coeff_single_dataset_then_combined_datasets_with_domain_weights
2343     return load_dataset(path, data_files=data_files_prefix+name, streaming=streaming, split=split).with_format("torch")
2344   File "/lfs/hyperturing2/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/div_coeff.py", line 64, in get_diversity_coefficient
2345     embedding, loss = Task2Vec(probe_network, classifier_opts={'seed': seed}).embed(tokenized_batch)
2346   File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/diversity/task2vec.py", line 133, in embed
2347     loss = self._finetune_classifier(dataset, loader_opts=self.loader_opts, classifier_opts=self.classifier_opts, max_samples=self.max_samples, epochs=epochs)
```

---

> Basically all data sets I use with streaming=True throw an unexpected error at some point when getting data form them on long runs. Especially the ones with the parquet option.

---

- cross posted hf discuss: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/hugging-face-error-equests-exceptions-connectionerror-protocolerror-connection-aborted-how-to-fix/51131
- discord HF: https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1146156148811112508/1146156148811112508
- SO: [Hugging face HTTP request on data from parquet format when the only way to get it is from the website's data viewer, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76923802/hugging-face-error-equests-exceptions-connectionerror-protocolerrorconnectio)

Comment: What dataset(s) from Hugging Face are you attempting to download? Where in your code/how are you attempting to download the dataset(s)? Could you also please remove any comments in the code posted that are irrelevant to the current problem?

Comment: Lastly, could you please post a complete traceback of the errors/exceptions encountered, or explain in the question why the traceback is split in two?

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg yes to all requests. Will do in a bit. Answering the easy one. Basically all data sets I use with `streaming=True` throw an unexpected error at some point when getting data form them on long runs. Especially the ones with the `parquet` option.

Comment: A back-up of the pile dataset (I presume this what you are trying to download based on your other posts) is available [here](https://huggingface.co/datasets/monology/pile). You can also use the [archive.org](https://archive.org/download/eleuther-ai-the-pile-v-1/pile_preliminary_components/) version.

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg do you know how to fork my own version of that data set to my HF datasets?

Comment: Ensure git-lfs then you should be able to run `git clone https://huggingface.co/datasets/monology/pile`. Then create another directory for your fork, move to it and run `huggingface-cli login` -> enter your credentials -> create a repo on HF (use the organisation flag if required) `huggingface-cli repo create your_fork_dataset_name --type dataset --organization your_org_name` -> create a clone of that HF repo you just created `git clone https://huggingface.co/datasets/username/your_fork_dataset_name` -> copy the necessary data from the original to your fork and commit and push as usual via Git

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
from typing import List, Dict, Optional, Union

import os
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

# Ensure you have the correct version of the Hugging Face 'datasets' library installed.
import datasets

# Configurable parameters
DATASET_NAME = "conceptofmind/pile_cc"
LOCAL_CACHE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("~/data/.cache")
os.makedirs(LOCAL_CACHE_DIR, exist_ok=True)

RETRY_TOTAL = 5
RETRY_BACKOFF_FACTOR = 0.2
RETRY_STATUS_FORCELIST = [500, 502, 503, 504]
TIMEOUT = 60 * 10

# Setup robust session
retry_strategy = Retry(
    total=RETRY_TOTAL,
    backoff_factor=RETRY_BACKOFF_FACTOR,
    status_forcelist=RETRY_STATUS_FORCELIST,
)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
http_session = requests.Session()
http_session.mount("https://", adapter)
http_session.mount("http://", adapter)

# Helper function
def robust_load_dataset(
    name: str,
    data_files: Union[str, List[str]],
    split: str,
    streaming: bool = False,
    use_auth_token: Union[bool, str] = True,  # Allow for actual token strings
    cache_dir: Optional[str] = None,
) -> datasets.Dataset:
    return datasets.load(
        path="parquet",
        name=name,
        data_files=data_files,
        split=split,
        streaming=streaming,
        cache_dir=cache_dir,
        download_config=datasets.DownloadConfig(
            cache_dir=cache_dir,
            use_etag=True,
            max_retries=retry_strategy,
            timeout=TIMEOUT,
            use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
            session=http_session,
        ),
    )

# Main example
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        dataset = robust_load_dataset(
            name=DATASET_NAME,
            data_files=LOCAL_CACHE_DIR,
            split="train",
            streaming=False,
            cache_dir=LOCAL_CACHE_DIR,
        )
        print(dataset)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to load dataset. Error: {e}")
```

Will fully test soon. Feedback welcomed.